# Paperclip Get dirty file before update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, public-activity

**Background:**

I'm developing Rails Application and in some models I'm using `paperclip gem` to save attachments. In same models I'm using `public_activity gem` to track the model changes & I've prepared Restore functionality based on that to be able to Undo changes on that model with specific conditions.
Now using paperclip option `:preserve_files => true` it's simple to get the old file in case of `delete`, but in case of `update`, I don't know how.

**Question:**

`public_activity gem` is already using `before_action` callback and I can handle all dirty fields except Paperclip file update.
So how can I get the dirty updated file without changing my models or adding extra callbacks (because I'm using this achievement in multiple models and Undo functionality is generic).

**Note:**

I'm using `File.exist?(paperclip_attachment.path)` to check whether the file is still exist or no, and it returns false in case of `update` callback of `public_activity` (I think it is same as `before_update` callback).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've did a simple way to get the dirty file with just edit Undo Functionality in `public_activity` update callback:

```
dirty_file_path = Dir.glob(File.join(File.dirname(paper_clip_attachment.path), '*.*')).max { |a,b| File.ctime(a) <=> File.ctime(b) }
```

`paper_clip_attachment.path` includes the path to the file, but the file itself is not yet created.

The code above just checks the container folder of the file `paper_clip_attachment.path` then checks the latest created file and save it's path to be used in Undo step.